# Why maven recognize dependencies and allows me to import but I cannot instantiate objects?

Tags: java, maven, command-line, jsoup

I just installed maven, and tried to use a dependency called Jsoup:

> mvn archetype:generate "-DgroupId=com.example" "-DartifactId=Foo" "-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart" "-DarchetypeVersion=1.4" "-DinteractiveMode=false"

> cd Foo  > mvn package

added these lines to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
  <version>1.15.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and then tried

> mvn package
> java -cp target\Foo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.example.App

the build was successful, but when the program runs it gives me this error:

```
C:\Users\brand\Desktop\java_misc\Foo>java -cp target\Foo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.example.App
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
        at com.example.App.main(App.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 1 more
```

I have done the same in eclipse with the exact same code and it works, which means that the XML dependency works, but I don't understand why it does not work when using just the command prompt. any help is appreciated thanks.

java code used to test was:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;


public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {


        try {   
                    String url = "https://www.stackoverflow.com";       
                    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                    System.out.println(document);
                
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need _all_ the jars on the classpath given to `-cp`

Comment: from the official page it says there is no need to download the jar though ?: https://jsoup.org/download "Maven
If you use Maven to manage the dependencies in your Java project, you do not need to download; just place the following into your POM's <dependencies> section:"

Comment: But you still have to specify all jars in the classpath

Comment: something like this?>java -cp "target\Foo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" "jsoup-1.15.3.jar" com.examp.App
Error: Could not find or load main class jsoup-1.15.3.jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jsoup-1.15.3.jar

Comment: it works now, I thought I had to separate jars with spaces, it looks like you need to use the ";" symbol instead. thanks for the help.